# How does Mac Mail choose the email server it uses to send an email?

Tags: mail.app

Say I have Mac Mail set up to use two mail-servers:  one for my private GMail account, and one for my work's Exchange account.

When I send an email, Mac Mail uses some mechanism to choose one of these two servers to contact to send the email.  Often it chooses correctly, but not 100% of the time.  For those cases where it sends via the "wrong" mail server, is there any way for me to tell it e.g. "all emails addressed to foo@bar.com should be sent via the GMail server" or "all emails addressed to baz@nerf.com should be sent via the Exchange Server" ?

Comment: It should be using the From: to determine the server to use.

Comment: @MarcWilson except I don't fill out a From field when I send an email, only a `To:` and (optionally) `CC:`, `Subject:`, and a message body.  (or to restate this question a different way, how does Mac Mail determine what string to put in the From: field when I have multiple email accounts set up?)

Comment: I don't use Mail.app any longer, but doesn't it have the concept of a default account?  When I did use it, it seems to me that From was a dropdown and you could choose the alias name.  It also had, if I remember correctly, the option reply via the address the mail was sent to.

Comment: @MarcWilson it does -- but that's the problem, when composing a new email, it sets the "From" dropdown to a fixed default, and if I'm in a hurry I often don't remember to change it to the "correct" address, and then the email gets sent from the wrong account.  Since I know that a given destination-address (e.g. `ceo@mycompany.com`) should always use the corresponding email-account (e.g. my Exchange account), it would be nice if I could somehow tell Mac Mail that rule and not get tripped up twice a week by accidentally sending from the wrong account.

Comment: @MarcWilson I don't think there is a default account. The from address seems to be chosen by your recent activity (I have not investigated in detail).

Comment: There are two potential issues. 1) The 'From' address (as displayed when composing the message) and 2) the SMTP server used when the message is sent. Whilst (2) is set in Mail > Preferences > Accounts > Server settings, I have found Mail to sometimes use a different SMTP server if sending to the specified one is not successful.